# Limit elasticsearch indexes in size and rollover when the limit is reached

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, elastic-stack, rollover

I've a docker container running `elasticsearch` and recently I've got into a situation when the container stopped because it ran out of space. Now I have no ability to start (it stops immediately) it and cleanup the disk.

I know I can write logs into different indexes (and I'm already doing that) on some time basis (daily) and then clean them, but even with this approach I can get into situation when my container generates so many logs so it can run out of space before my cleanup job starts and will be broken.

- How can I prevent this situation with `elasticsearch` in future, just
  to make sure my indexes take no more than limit I defined?
- Is there a better way to manage disk space taken by `elasticsearch` logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have size limits. Elasticsearch is not fixed-size db like Whisper. Try to optimize your indexed data or mapping to reduce index size, or create/clean new indices hourly.

Comment: got it, any best practices for cleanup tools/scripts? What should it like, how is the best to run?

Comment: not yet, just writing all the logs via restful from various systems

Comment: you need a central service that will receive logs from other places and send them to ES, while keeping track of created indices, usual combination is logstash+curator, but it's totally ok to make your own service.